# Vim に ddc.vim プラグインを入れたが、一文字しか補完されない

Tags: vim

Vim に ddc.vim プラグインを入れたのですが、補完をしようとしても一文字しか補完されません。

例えば、p と打って、候補にある `printf` を選択した場合、`pr` としか出てこないのです。
解決方法わかる方教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 念のため Vim のバージョンも記載してみてください。また、ddc.vim について次のページによると "インストールしただけではddc.vimは使えず" とあります。参考: [Vimの新しい自動補完プラグイン「ddc.vim」を使ってみた](https://note.com/dd_techblog/n/n97f2b6ca09d8) / インストールや設定にあたって参考にしたページや、あなた自身が実際に行った手順等をもう少し詳しく記載してみてください。

Comment: vim のバージョンは9.0です。
一度プラグインをアンインストールして
https://note.com/dd_techblog/n/n97f2b6ca09d8
上記のURLの通りにプラグインを入れて、vimrcも書き換えました。
インサートモードに切り替え、文字を入力すると、本来INSERT と書かれる場所に[ddc] ['vim-lsp']　と、背景が赤色で出てきます。
文字を入力すると本当に一瞬だけINSERTと出ますが、またすぐに[ddc] ['vim-lsp']に戻ります。
上記のURLでは、Tabで補完と書いてありましたが、Tabで補完されることはなく、Tabキーは本来の動きもしない状態です。
対処法わかれば教えていただきたいです。